# Как скачать файл себе на сервер по ссылке, если в ссылке нет названия?

Tags: php

Есть ссылка, к примеру site.ru/down/file=123 если перейти по ней то скачается файл, так вот
Как скачать его на сервер ?

Comment: а в чем проблема     copy("http://site.ru/down/file=123","my.file")     не работает?

Comment: я не знаю какой файл скачается, не знаю его имени и расширения.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mime-content-type.php